# Internet Explorer 8 Restrictions Registry Locations

Tags: internet-explorer-8, registry, toolbar, restriction

I'm attempting to restrict IE8 to no toolbars, no anything.

I'm working with Kiosk mode, in Windows XP Home edition.

I have some XP pro computers set up properly with this already, using Group Edit and Windows Steady State.

However, I have been unable to set it up the same way on both XP pro and XP home:

On XP pro, whenever a new window is opened via link, it opens in a small window with no toolbars.  In XP home, when a new window is opened via link, it opens a standard browser window, with all the toolbars still there.

I know I can disable the toolbars somehow in the registry, but I have not been able to find where; All the information online that I have seen has not sent me to any existing registry location.

Anyone Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware, you can start IE in kiosk mode from the cmd line - by running iexplore -k followed by the web address you want to open. If the registry values that you need to use to lock down the browser aren't there, you can just create them.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Restrictions

Create them as DWORD values - with a value of 1 enforcing the policy.

NoBrowserClose (disables closing the browser window)

NoBrowserContextMenu (disables right-click context menu)

NoFileOpen (disables use of Ctrl-O or Ctrl-L to launch an arbitrary URL)

NoOpenInNewWnd (disables opening a link in a new window via Ctrl-N or Shift-click)

These should pretty much cover all of the normal ways a user could circumvent kiosk mode.

In addition to the above, there are also:

```
AlwaysPromptWhenDownload - Always prompt user when downloading files.
NoBrowserBars - Disable changes to browsers bars.
NoBrowserClose - Disable the option of closing Internet Explorer.
NoBrowserContextMenu - Disable right-click context menu.
NoBrowserOptions - Disable the Tools > Internet Options menu.
NoBrowserSaveAs - Disable the ability to Save As.
NoFavorites - Disable the Favorites.
NoFileNew - Disable the File > New command.
NoFileOpen - Disable the File > Open command.
NoFindFiles - Disable the Find Files command.
NoNavButtons - Disables the Forward and Back navigation buttons
NoOpeninNewWnd - Disable Open in New Window option.
NoPrinting - Remove Print and Print Preview from the File menu.
NoSelectDownloadDir - Disable the option of selecting a download directory.
NoTheaterMode - Disable the Full Screen view option.
NoViewSource - Disable the ability to view the page source HTML.
RestGoMenu - Remove Mail and News menu item.
```

Comment: I have the browser already open in kiosk mode.  The original window does not show any toolbars;  However, when we open a second window (which is part of how we need it to work), the browser toolbars return.  Is there a DWORD I could set to disable the toolbar?

Comment: Oh, so you need to open a new window and maintain kiosk mode. How is the second window being opened?

Comment: If you are displaying a site of your own design you could use this script (or something like it): [Kiosk Mode script](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/kiosk-mode-link-t1197943.html). I'm trying to find a reference of the available registry keys for IE8, but so far no luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help, George!  You definitely pointed me in the right direction!  Still got a bit to go, but taking things steps at a time. =)

Comment: Oh, and the second window is being opened by a link on the page.

If I am not mistaken, the entire main page is a FLASH plugin so I do not know what exact method is being used to open the link in a new window.

Comment: Ok - I have some ideas, but will need to do a little research first. I'll get back to you as soon as I can. G

Comment: Shouldn't the path for this be HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Restrictions

Comment: Neither path exists. Not for: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ Policies\Microsoft Internet Explorer\Restrictions OR HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Restrictions And creating those registry edits does not seem to work. Additionally, I would like to know why my comment is being deleted.

Comment: I was able to get this to work using: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Restrictions]
"NoBrowserClose"=dword:00000000